# Dividing a long output file

Tags: python, multithreading, ubuntu, logging, stdout

The way I create a log file for my application in ubuntu, is via stdout:
I am running the app and writing the output into a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
_file=/"home/log_main.log"
sudo python /home/main.py >>$_file 2>&1 

exit 0
```

If my app is running for too long, the file it creates it too big. Therefore, I want to create a thread inside my app that every once in a while copy the content of "log_main.log" file into a new file "log{#}.txt", and than deleting the content of "log main"

```
from threading import Thread
import logging
import time
import os

FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s - %(levelname)-6s: %(name)-s: %(message)s'
DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=FORMAT, datefmt=DATE_FORMAT)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger("main logger")
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.propagate = False
logger.debug('Logging Start')

def secondary_log():
    is_file = os.path.isfile('log_main.log')
    print("is_file {}".format(is_file))
    t0_sec = time.time()
    logger.debug("t0_sec | {}".format(t0_sec))

    txt_num =0
    while True:
        if time.time() - t0_sec > 2:
            t0_sec = time.time()
            main_txt = open("log_main.log", 'r+')
            content = main_txt.readlines()
            main_txt.truncate(0)
            main_txt.close()

            sec_txt = open("log{}.txt".format(txt_num), "w+")
            txt_num +=1

            for x in content:
                sec_txt.write(x)

            sec_txt.close()
        time.sleep(0.1)


def main_log():
    i= 0
    t0_main = time.time()
    logger.debug("t0_main | {}".format(t0_main))
    while time.time() - t0_main < 10:
        logger.debug(i)
        i +=1
        time.sleep(0.0001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sec_log_thread = Thread(target=secondary_log)
    # main_log_thread = Thread(target=main_log)
    sec_log_thread.daemon = True
    sec_log_thread.start()
    main_log()
```

However, the problem is that on the interval between reading the content of the "log_main" (`content = main_txt.readlines()`) and deleting its content (`main_txt.truncate(0)`), a new output may arise (from `logger.debug(i)`) which I can miss, and lose this information. Does any body have an idea for a solution?

(Why not use logging handler instead, you might ask?. Because it slows down my application)

Comment: The better way is to write to the log file directly in your app, with a rotating log file. No threads needed. See e.g. [the documentation for the `RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler). Capturing both stdout and stderr into a file on the command line is nice for a quick one-off use, but not sustainable for future use (as you've already noticed).

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your comment.
From trial and error, I saw that using the logging package in python in order to write to a file slows down my application

Comment: You're already using the logging package! So I don't understand why you now say it's slowing your program down. Even more so, writing to file instead of stderr/stdout will normally be *faster* (no terminal formatting). You would basically just need to change the handler from using stderr to using a (rotating) file.

Comment: I am using the logging package, but not the handler which writes the log files. I have no explanation for why it slows it down, but empirically it did.
Another reason to keep this way of logging is that it logs from many different modules with different loggers. So changing to a new way of logging will include some reformatting. 
Perhaps eventually I will need to use the 'RotatingFileHandler', but I wonder if there is a way to solve it using the current way of logging

Comment: Redirection is made before starting your process, and file is managed by shell - which is separate process. Opening and modifying the same file inside other (yours) process will lead to multiprocessing issues and errors.  Moreover you are running it with sudo - so your app will have different user context than shell-made redirections. If logging module leads to poor performance, maybe you could redirect standard output inside your app?

Comment: By running linux commands from python? That's possible. However, It still doesn't solve the issue of losing information while copying the file.

Comment: if you really want to keep this solution, you may also try to synchronize threads with lock: put logging in main thread into lock context manager and use this lock inside file-rotation thread, to prevent emiting log entries during file truncation. It will put sume overhead, but you could give it a try.